# Latex file saved as .pdf instead of.tex format accidentally

Tags: pdf

I have saved my `.tex` file as `.pdf` accidentally and I cannot open now this `.odf` file. How can I recover it? Thanks.

Comment: If the file is just saved as `.pdf` it's not in `.pdf` format, I assume (unless it is exported, that's different). You should be able to change the extension easily (on Linux with `move foo.pdf foo.tex` or with a right click on the file name -> change name etc. on Windows). And I think this question is off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a `.tex` file is normally very close to pure text, open it in  a text editor, verify if it is not garbled, and save it with a `.tex` extension.